# Writing to local variable vs caching in sequential memory access

Tags: c, caching

So I would write testing code for this but I am really confused how to do so since results would be cached between tests.

Essentially my question comes down to is

```
int sum = 0;
int last = arr[0];
sum += last;
int current = arr[1];
sum += last * current;
last = current;
current = arr[2]
sum += last * current;
.... (continuing on for a very long time)
```

Going to be any faster than

```
int sum = 0;
sum += arr[0];
sum += arr[0] * arr[1];
sum += arr[1] * arr[2];
...
```

Due to caching. Lets assume that the block size for the cache was the size of an int so each access is in a new block. The difference in them is that in theory the first sample reads the memory less often. However since caching would make the second read faster I am not sure whether saving it to a temporary variable would be faster than a cache hit.

The reason I am asking is I am trying to write efficient code to go over a 2D array/matrix and have each element calculated as a function of what is around it

```
x a x
b e c
x d x

So e = a * b * c * d
```

I could see myself writing it easily as

```
for (int y = 1; y < height - 1; y++) {
   for (int x = 1; x < width - 1; x++) {
      newCell[y][x] = oldCell[y+1][x] * oldCell[y-1][x] * oldCell[y][x+1] * oldCell[y][x-1]
   }
}
```

But perhaps a version with less memory accesses would look like this

```
for (int y = 1; y < height - 1; y++) {
   int last = oldCell[y][0];
   int current = oldCell[y][1];
   for (int x = 1; x < width - 1; x++) {
      int future = oldCell[y][x+1];
      newCell[y][x] = oldCell[y+1][x] * oldCell[y-1][x] * future * last;
      last = current;
      current = future;
   }
}
```

I could potentially also get something going with the Ys as well to lower those memory accesses.

My gut instinct here is that the second version would not be any faster but I cant put my finger on why.

Comment: I don't think the easy version will work properly. You'll be updating `[1][1]`, and then using the updated value in the calculation for `[1][2]`. That's typically not what you want with this kind of algorithm. And the same problem exists in the `y` direction.